# Doubles - Assign, Retain, Readwrite?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management

I'm parsing an XML document containing latitude/longitudes into custom DTO objects. When I try to set a label from a double value I get an error, yet logging to the console works. I'm convinced this is a memory issue. I have this code:

```
@interface LocationResult : NSObject {
    LoginResultType result;
    LocationInfo *location;
}
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) LoginResultType result;
@property (nonatomic, retain) LocationInfo *location;

@end

@interface LocationInfo : NSObject {
    LatLng *location;
    NSString *niceLocation;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) LatLng *location;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *niceLocation;

-(LocationInfo *)initWithLocation:(NSString *)strNiceLocation latitudeIs:(double)latitude longitudeIs:(double)lonitude withPostCode:(NSString *)postCode;

@end

@interface LatLng : NSObject {
    NSString *postCode;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *postCode;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) double latitude;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) double longitude;

-(LatLng*)initWithLocation:(NSString *)strPostCode latitudeIs:(double)latitude longitudeIs:(double)longitude;

@end
```

To initialize the object, I'm parsing from an XML doc using TouchXML:

```
    NSString *postCode =[[eleData nodeForXPath:@"Location/PostCode" error:nil] stringValue];
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [formatter setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:TRUE];
    NSString *rawLat =[ [eleData nodeForXPath:@"Location/Latitude" error:nil] stringValue]; 
    double lat = [rawLat doubleValue];
    NSString *rawLng = [[eleData nodeForXPath:@"Location/Longitude" error:nil] stringValue];
    double lng = [rawLng doubleValue];
    [info initWithLocation:prettyLocation latitudeIs:lat longitudeIs:lng withPostCode:postCode];
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", lat]); // works
    NSLog(info.location.postCode); // works
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", info.location.latitude]); // works
```

To display the data:

```
lblCurrentPostcode.text = result.location.location.postCode;
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d, %d", result.location.location.latitude, result.location.location.longitude]); // this works
lblCoords.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", result.location.location.latitude, result.location.location.longitude]; // message sent to deallocated instance exception, crashes app
lblCoords.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f", result.location.location.latitude, result.location.location.longitude]; // message sent to deallocated instance exception, crashes app
```

I don't understand why I can log to the console and set the text of PostCode (an NSString*), but not set the text for the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Connect lblCords using interface builder or

```
lblCoords = [[UILabel alloc] init];

lblCoords.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", result.location.location.latitude, result.location.location.longitude];  
lblCoords.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f", result.location.location.latitude, result.location.location.longitude];
```

Comment: The label is connected in IB. I can set the text if I do `lblCoords.text = @"blah";`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `lblCoords` label has been deallocated, as the message states :

> message sent to deallocated instance exception

while trying to use the setter for `text`. Check out the way you manage this label. `double` type isn't object type, and there is no need to care about memory managment for them (this is also true for other base types like `int`, ...).

Comment: It's connected with interface builder, and I can set the text to a plain NSString.

Comment: does the property `retain` the label ? it is deallocated when you try to access it

Comment: Yes it does, the declaration is `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *lblCoords;`. I can access it without any problem, and can set it's text to a precompiled string.